# Trailing UILabel Error across entire app randomly started to appear

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, storyboard

I started getting a weird trailing cut-off across a lot of my UIlabels which wasn't happening before testing today. The last few weeks since starting development the app has been running smoothly and I was seeing no issues up until today. Essentially any label that doesn't have a trailing constraint was getting cut off even though it aligned to the leading edge of superview and the label was a word or two.

The strange part is when my device is running and connected to XCode it's fine, but as soon as I unplug it I get these cut-offs happening. Not sure what to do...I've tried restarting my device and computer but to no luck.

Didn't think for every label I needed a trailing constraint - especially one that doesn't change text and is manually done in storyboard.

Edit: I'm using Firebase/Firestore to handle all data just to throw that out there as I know it can act up and be tricky sometimes

Thanks for any and all help

Comment: You need to always set the trailing constraint to avoid cut-offs on different screen sizes, otherwise, iOS won't know how to calculate the width of the `UILabel`.

Comment: It's better to do what is good and connect the constraints to prevent issues in the future.